# How can I see a url link inside a PDF file opened in Safari or in Preview without open that link?

Tags: macos, safari, pdf, preview, url

I've got a PDF file with an Image inside that has a url link to a page.
I need to see that link without opening it.
I expect to see this link when I move the mouse on the image, but I can't see it anywhere.
Is there a way to see the link in Safari or in Preview in Yosemite?

### UPDATE

The problem is that I have a working web link on an image inside the PDF, and below a non working one, but only in Safari and Preview. It works perfectly in Chrome. the PDF is generated by myself with the fpdf library.

Comment: Easiest way might be to just disconnect from the Internet and then open it, though you might be able to drag the link to your desktop.

Comment: the "real" problem is that I have a working link and below a non working one, but only in Safari and Preview. It works perfectly in Chrome. the PDF is generated by myself with the fadf library.